# Is there a null value in maxima?

Tags: maxima

I have the following two functions:

```
find(list, closure) := block(
  filter: sublist(list, closure),
  if length(filter) > 0 then filter[1] else null)$

find_index(list, closure) := block(
  filter: sublist_indices(list, closure),
  if length(filter) > 0 then filter[1] else null)$
```

In other languages I would return `null` or `nil` here, if the element that is searched can't be found. But I think this keyword doesn't exist in maxima. What is the common convention in maxima for what to return in this case? Maybe `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`false` is indeed the most commonly used value to represent "not there". It is not required, but there is a pretty consistent convention for it.

Note that `if foo then bar` evaluates to `false` if `foo` evaluates to `false`. Therefore `if foo then bar else false` is equivalent to `if foo then bar`, which is a little shorter.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

> -- Constant: false
>
> ```
>  'false' represents the Boolean constant of the same name.  Maxima
>  implements 'false' by the value 'NIL' in Lisp.
> ```

So the lisp equivalent of an empty result is `false`.